# Make a grouped bar chart in DC.js with multiple checkboxes

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

How do I make a grouped bar chart with checkboxes to hide/show individual series?

**When the check box is selected, it should add a series to each group of the bar chart.**
I want to use **dc.js**

The output should be similar to this snapshot.
[image: Expected grouped bar chart]

My sample data set

```
data = [{"under 5 years":12, "5 to 13 years":87, "14 to 17 years":25,"18 to 24 years":15,"25 to 44 years":25,"45 to 64 years":14,"place":"CA"},
{"under 5 years":12, "5 to 13 years":87, "14 to 17 years":25,"18 to 24 years":15,"25 to 44 years":25,"45 to 64 years":14,"place":"TX"},

{"under 5 years":12, "5 to 13 years":87, "14 to 17 years":25,"18 to 24 years":15,"25 to 44 years":25,"45 to 64 years":14,"place":"NY"},

{"under 5 years":12, "5 to 13 years":87, "14 to 17 years":25,"18 to 24 years":15,"25 to 44 years":25,"45 to 64 years":14,"place":"TX"},

{"under 5 years":12, "5 to 13 years":87, "14 to 17 years":25,"18 to 24 years":15,"25 to 44 years":25,"45 to 64 years":14,"place":"FL"},

{"under 5 years":12, "5 to 13 years":87, "14 to 17 years":25,"18 to 24 years":15,"25 to 44 years":25,"45 to 64 years":14,"place":"IL"},

{"under 5 years":12, "5 to 13 years":87, "14 to 17 years":25,"18 to 24 years":15,"25 to 44 years":25,"45 to 64 years":14,"place":"NY"}]
```

Comment: You're attracting negative attention for two reasons: 1) adding over-broad tags like javascript and d3.js is an invitation for hate 2) You need to say a little bit about what you've tried. I'll edit so hopefully this doesn't get closed.

Comment: Thank you, Gordon. https://codepen.io/Rastikko/pen/GqNbqM, this is the fiddle I've taken as a reference, how do I add cross-filter and get the results wrt to the data mentioned in the question.